# Maximum size of a graph with given girth

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am unable to get the bound on the maximum size of a graph of order $n$ with girth $g$. Is there any literature regarding this. I know that there is an asymptotic bound on the size of a graph $G$ with even girth $2k$ and order $n$. Is there a similar one for arbitrary grith? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Could you please tell what is bound for even girth? It should be easily extended for odd girth.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami From [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5167.pdf), theorem 4.1 and its corollary, we have that the maximum number of edges for a graph with order $n$ and even girth $2k$ is less than $\frac{n+n^{1+\frac1{k}}}{2}$. Note, however that when we take the complete graph, which has girth $3$, this bound fails